# Can you use center of charge to find electric field of a not-centered point near a uniformly charged rod?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

[image]

Suppose we have a uniformly-charged rod has charge density $+\lambda$, and we want to know the magnitude of the components of electric field at point $P$. The standard method of solving for the electric field involves setting up integrals over the length of the rod.

I hypothesized that I could reach an equivalent result for the electric field if I found the center of charge ($\frac{a-b}{2}$) and used the $E=\frac{kQ}{r^2}$ definition of electric field, subbing in $\lambda(a+b)$ for $Q$, $\sqrt{(\frac{a-b}{2})^2+c^2}$ for $r$, and using cosine and sine for the horizontal and vertical components, respectively. Is this a valid way to approach the problem, i.e., can you solve for electric field of a uniformly charged rod by using the total charge and center of charge? I have so far been unable to prove it, but it seems like an intuitive solution.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: Sorry, @VincentThacker, if it was not clear, but this is not a homework question, and I don't think it's really a "check my work question" as I'm interested in the concept not the details/final answer. My question is whether or not it is valid to solve for electric field of a uniform line of charge (in cases where Gauss' law is not applicable) by using the total charge and the center of charge. Is this edited version better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. I did this in a first year physics assignment and rightly lost marks for it. The center of charge concept is helpful for finding out how a charged object *responds* to a uniform field that you already know. To compute it in the first place though, there is no way around the integral.

The electric field produced by a charge distribution depends on its shape and you lose information when you approximate it as a point charge. More precisely, what you get corresponds to the first term in the [multipole expansion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368933/understanding-multipole-expansion-in-classical-electrodynamics?rq=1) of the potential.